# wxPython: Populate menu in sub panel

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython

I have a wx application where the main frame has several sub panels. I'd like to have a menu bar in the main frame, where each of the menus is associated with a panel. This means that the creation of menu items and binding them to event handlers should be done in the individual panels and not in the main frame. Here is a minimal example:

```
import wx


class myPanel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, menubar):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        menu = wx.Menu()
        menuAction1 = menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Action1')
        menuAction2 = menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Action2')

        menubar.Append(menu, '&Actions')

        # This does not work because the EVT_MENU is only seen by the main frame(?)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onAction1, menuAction1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onAction2, menuAction2)

    def onAction1(self, event):
        print('Hello1')

    def onAction2(self, event):
        print('Hello2')


class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        # There are more panels in my actual program
        self.panel1 = myPanel1(self, self.menubar)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel1, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=1)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.Layout()


class myApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = mainWindow(parent=None, title='Title')
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        frame.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = myApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The problem is now that myPanel1.onAction1 is not called because the menu event from the main frame does not propagate to the sub panel.
Is there any neat way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I've found the answer myself. It's as simple as changing

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onAction1, menuAction1)
```

in `myPanel1.__init__` to

```
self.GetParent().Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onAction1, menuAction1)
```

Anyway, thanks everyone who thought about this question for their effort.